# yaml safe_load of many different objects

Tags: deserialization, yaml, pyyaml

I have a huge YAML file with tag definitions like in this snippet

```
- !!python/object:manufacturer.Manufacturer
  name: aaaa
  address: !!python/object:address.BusinessAddress {street: bbbb, number: 123, city: cccc}
```

And I needed to load this, first to make sure that the file is correct YAML, second to extract information at a certain tree-dept given a certain context. I had this all as nested dicts, lists and primitives that would be straightforward  to do. But I cannot load the file as I don't have the original Python sources and class defines, so `yaml.load()` is out.
I have tried `yaml.safe_load()` but that throws and exception. 
The BaseLoader loads the file, so it is correct. But that jumbles all primitive information (number, datetime) together as strings.

Then I found [How to deserialize an object with PyYAML using safe_load?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2627555/5968392), since the file has over 100 different tags defined, the solutions presented there is impractical.

Do I have to use some other tools to strip the !!tag definitions (there is at least one occasion where `!!` occurs inside a normal string), so I can use safe_load. Is there simpler way to do solve this that I am not aware of?

If not I will have to do some string parsing to get the types back, but I thought I ask here first.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to go the cumbersome route of adding any of the classes if you want to use the `safe_loader()` on such a file.

You should have gotten an `ConstructorError` thrown in `SafeConstructor.construct_undefined()` in `constructor.py`. That method gets registered for the fall through case 'None' in the `constructor.py` file.

If you combine that info with the fact that all such tagged "classes" are mappings (and not lists or scalars), you can just copy the code for the mappings in a new function and register that as the fall-through case.

```
import yaml
from yaml.constructor import SafeConstructor

def my_construct_undefined(self, node):
    data = {}
    yield data
    value = self.construct_mapping(node)
    data.update(value)

SafeConstructor.add_constructor(
    None, my_construct_undefined)

yaml_str = """\
- !!python/object:manufacturer.Manufacturer
  name: aaaa
  address: !!python/object:address.BusinessAddress {street: bbbb, number: 123, city: cccc}
"""

data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
print(data)
```

should get you:

```
[{'name': 'aaaa', 'address': {'city': 'cccc', 'street': 'bbbb', 'number': 123}}]
```

without an exception thrown, and with "number" as integer not as string.